# What is the closest translation of "commeruero" to English?

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation, grammar-choice

My working understanding is best expressed as "I will have fully earned", with "commeruero" being the first-person singular future perfect active indicative form of commereo. If I am far from the mark, I would really appreciate an explanation of why my interpretation is incorrect in non-technical terms, since I am not only uneducated in Latin, but also have little knowledge of the structure of languages in general - so it may be the case that even the meaning of the conjugation I have written is not as I understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not entirely wrong, but it should be noted that [commereo](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DC%3Aentry+group%3D69%3Aentry%3Dcommereo) has negative connotations. For example, Ovid uses it with *poenam* ('earned the punishment'),  and the comic poets coupled it frequently with *culpam* to mean something like "committed the crime." (I earned the blame = I did the deed.)

For 'earned' in a positive or neutral sense, you can use *mereo* and an adverb. This is the same word but without the *com-* prefix.

"I will have earned" is the English future perfect, which in Latin is formed by taking the perfect active stem and adding the future perfect endings, which you can find [here](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/verb-endings).

In this case, the perfect active stem is *meru-*, and the first person singular indicative ending is *-ero*, giving you: **meruero**, "I will have earned."

For "fully," I don't think there's a prefix you can add to *mereo* to get you your desired meaning, but there are plenty of adverbs. A good one, in my opinion, is *omnino*, giving you the fuller sentence:

***Omnino meruero***, "I will have completely/fully earned"

You can even add whatever it is you have earned in the accusative case; if it's e.g. "praise," the sentence would be: **laudam omnino meruero**.